# parse error: premature EOF in fromJSON() when opening bad URL

Tags: r

This statement gives me an error.

```
somevar <- fromJSON('https://www.predictit.org/api/Public/GetMarketChartData/99999?timespan=90d&maxContracts=9999&showHidden=true')

Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : parse error: premature EOF
                                       
                     (right here) ------^
```

How do I set this up so that if there is an error my R script can handle it without crashing? Instead, I want `somevar` to become a blank string or `FALSE` if `fromJSON()` encounters an error opening the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I usually do it, which fails if (a) there is no connection to the server or the file, but (b1) safely obtains an empty json (i.e. `list()`) if there is a connection to a file, yet it turns out an unreadable/malformated json.
It should be shorter to implement purrr's `safely()` or `possibly()`, yet you would need to distinguish between connection errors and parsing errors.

```
  safe_fromJSON <- function(txt, encoding = "UTF-8") {
  
  obj_lines <- readLines(con = txt, encoding = encoding)
  
  check_json <- jsonlite::validate(txt = obj_lines)
  if(check_json == TRUE ) {
    obj_json <- fromJSON(txt = obj_lines)
  } else {
    obj_json <- fromJSON(txt = "[]") # "[]" represents an empty json.
  }
  
  obj_json
}

safe_fromJSON(txt = "https://www.predictit.org/api/Public/GetMarketChartData/99999?timespan=90d&maxContracts=9999&showHidden=true")
list()
```